# I need help interpreting this set notation problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

everybody, I just need help interpreting  $(P\cap$Q)' $\cap$ (P$\cup$Q)

I thought it would have been,

P and Q don't intersect but intersects all of P and Q

but I'm wrong why?

Comment: Have you read up on set theory? Do you know what $\cap$, and $\cup$ means? The $'$ is most likely complementation (do you know what that means?).

Comment: And what has this to do with probability and statistics?

Comment: I know $\cap$ is the intersection between two sets in my case P and Q. $\cup$ is the union of two sets meaning all of set P and Q.

Comment: Are you talking about complementary events?

Comment: Complementary sets - you haven't told us what this has to do with probability and statistics. It looks like you've pulled it out of context...

Comment: [probability & statistics tags deleted]

Comment: So, I'm currently studying venn diagrams and karnaugh maps and some of the problems involve probability.

Comment: So what does ' mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong or right depending on the interpretation of english. Natural languages sometimes are somewhat fuzzy about the semantics which is inadequate for mathematics sometimes. This means that when using natural language you have to stay clear from these traps.

The complement of a set is the set of elements not contained in the other set. That is $(P\cap Q)'$ is the set of element that is not in both $P$ and $Q$. And the set $P\cup Q$ is the set of elements that is in $P$ or $Q$ (or both). Finally when intersecting these sets it means that it's the set of elements that is in $P$ or $Q$, but not both (to see this we can use a venn diagram).

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes much more sense now. The complementary between two sets is where I was stuck. Cheers everybody.